# DataRetrievalFailureException: '__type__' Not Found in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Neo4j REST database set up and running and I was trying to access it using Spring Data Neo4j. The following code:

```
MyObject obj = myObjectRepository.findOne(1234L);
```

throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataRetrievalFailureException: '__type__' on `http://my.ip.addr.ess:7474/db/data/node/1234;` nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' on `http://my.ip.addr.ess:7474/db/data/node/1234`

Note that if I navigate to `http://my.ip.addr.ess:7474/db/data/node/1234`, my object shows up correctly.

In my pom I have `org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j-rest:2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: is it a question typo or do you really have "1234L" with L in your code?

Comment: nope, the `L` is just java syntax to indicate that `1234` is a `Long`

Comment: How did you create your object in the db? Can you share the code that does it, also the class declaration for `MyObject` and your Repository and your spring configuration.

Comment: Michael, I created neo4j db with a Python script. Am I supposed to use Spring to import data in the DB in order to being able to use it later for graph manipulation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same issue. Seems I am required to have a **type** property on the db node obj. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to a add a property to your node called "__type__" and give it the value of your objects class name. E.g. in your example you would add to your node:

property: __type__ value: "MyObject"